# Issue accessing the TFS server though the web

Tags: tfs

I have TFS 2010 set up on TESTServer.
If I am on the server (logged in as administrator) I can access the web portal for TFS using the following

```
http://TESTServer:8080/tfs/web/
```

but when I am on my own computer still in the same network, when I try the same URL, I get challenged for a username and password.  Even when I enter the administrator details, it does not accept them.

Also I tried the following

```
http://TESTServer:8080/services/v1.0/ServerStatus.asmx?op=CheckAuthentication
```

Which says the resource can not be found

***** update***

I got it to work with the IP address... but if I ping the name it gets the correct IP address??

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Are you running a domain or a workgroup?

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot connect to `http://TFSSERVER:8080/services/v1.0/ServerStatus.asmx?op=CheckAuthentication` it could be that you have incorrect proxy settings in your organization. Could it be the *proxy settings* have changed?

Have you checked your *host file* for any entries regarding your TFS server?

Can you open a *telnet session to port 8080* on your TFS Server?

[Grant Holliday wrote a couple of steps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/granth/archive/2008/06/26/troubleshooting-connections-to-tfs.aspx) you can do to troubleshoot TFS connection issues.